# Is an option tag that can have any inner HTML value inserted into it XSS-able?

Tags: xss

Consider the following code:

```
<select>
    <option>ANY VALUE</option>
</select>
```

Users on my website have the ability to add option tags to a list that can have any value inserted into it. Adding tags to this list is not effective as it displays the string literally when in the option list.

In the HTML spec, the permitted contents of an option tag is only normal character data.

Is there a value a malicious user could insert to launch an XSS attack using this?

Comment: it depends on how the user adds it; if it's "printed" by the server, then yes, if done via JS post load, then no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
</option></select><img src=no onerror=alert(1)>
```

There are some tags in which tags are not parsed (textarea or title would be two other examples), but an attacker can of course just break out of those contexts.

The injection takes place inside a normal HTML context,so HTML encoding dangerous characters - `<` and `>` would be enough, but it is good practice to encode `'` and `"` as well - is the correct solution here.

Comment: I prefer `<svg onload="...">` these days, as it's slightly more compact than img and doesn't require an extra request, but the basic form is what I was going to say here too. Of course, in this context, you could just put `<script>...</script>` instead.

Comment: But...html entities don't render in an option block! So it (and any other html special characters) will show up in the option block like `&lt;/select&gt;` instead of `</select>`.  So the only solution I see is to search and replace `</select>` before outputting and leave everything else as is.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @CaptainHypertext I tried it with Firefox and Chrome, and they render in both. What browser are you using? Anyway, I would not filter for `</select>` as it seems quite error prone. An alternative may be to filter for `<`, `>`, `"`, and maybe `'`.

Comment: @tim Huh, I think you're right.  Did a static html test and it works.  Maybe something's funny in my app, I'll check it later, thanks.